# WiFi country changed to US, how do I change it back?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, eeepc

My EeePC running Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly didn't see my wireless network on channel 13 any more, about July 23 2014.

`iw reg get` says it's set to `country US`.

`iw reg get` on my other laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 and not updated for a while says `country 00` and it works fine.

`sudo iw reg set SE` solves the problem but only until reboot, what is the correct way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=SE
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.